# R - return to numbers from cut

Tags: r, string, list, cut

I have a table with the cuts in intervals like:

```
    bin targets casos   prop phyp      logit
(-2,-1]     193  6144 0.0314    0 -3.4286244
  (-1,3]     128   431 0.2970    1 -0.8617025
 (3,11]     137   245 0.5592    1  0.2378497
```

I want to get the original cuts. I tried with:

```
a<-strsplit(as.character(pl$table[,'bin']), ' ')
```

And then I tried to split each row with:

```
lapply(a, function(x) strsplit(x, ",")[1] )
```

But I don't get the expected result, which is:

```
(-1,3,11)
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? What else do I need to do to get to the result?

Thanks.

Comment: `unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$bin, ","), function(x) max(as.numeric(gsub("\\(|]", "", x)))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, there are more bounds than you say you are hoping to retrieve.  This will give you all bounds:

```
d <- read.table(text='    bin targets casos   prop phyp      logit
"(-2,-1]"     193  6144 0.0314    0 -3.4286244
  "(1,3]"     128   431 0.2970    1 -0.8617025
 "(3,11]"     137   245 0.5592    1  0.2378497', header=T)

strings <- as.character(levels(d$bin))
strings <- substr(strings, 2, nchar(strings)-1)
unique(unlist(strsplit(strings, ",")))
# [1] "-2" "-1" "1"  "3"  "11"
```

If you only wanted the upper bounds, this will work:

```
strings <- as.character(levels(d$bin))
strings <- sapply(strsplit(strings, ","), function(l){ l[2] })
strings <- substr(strings, 1, nchar(strings)-1)
unique(strings)
# [1] "-1" "3"  "11"
```

Comment: thanks. I realized that and changed it in the example.

Answer (score 3):

If your data is consistently in this format, you could use `gsub()`.

```
df <- data.frame(bin = c('(-2,-1]','(1,3]','(3,11]'),
                 targets = c(193, 128, 137), 
                 casos = c(6144, 431, 245),
                 prop = c(0.0314, 0.297, 0.5592),
                 phyp = c(0,1,1),
                 logit = c(-3.4286244,-0.8617025, 0.2378497), stringsAsFactors = F)

a <- strsplit(df$bin, ',')
sapply(a, function(x) gsub("]", "", x))[2,]
sapply(a, function(x) gsub("\\(", "", x))[1,]
```

Which gives you

```
[1] "-1" "3"  "11"
[1] "-2" "1"  "3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be:

```
a<-strsplit(as.character(pl$table[,'bin']), ' ')
lapply(a, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, ",|]"))[2])
```